# iPhone SDK: Delete cookies of a specific webview

Tags: iphone, xcode4, uiwebview

I would like to know if there is a way to delete the cookies but only of a specific webview. For example, I have two webviews in which they both load facebook.com. When I log on to facebook in one webview the other logs in as well. I don't want this. I want each webview to have their own instance of facebook. So when I log on to facebook in one webview, the other webview stays at the log in screen. I've researched and found out that I can delete cookies to clear the data, however when I do this both webviews automatically log off of facebook instead of just one. So, I was wondering if there was a way to specifically delete the cookies of a certain webview. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class.pdf).

Comment: No where there does it mention anything about implementing the cookies to a webview.